# Can we drag N drop Slinks in BALKAN GRAPH OrgChartJS

Tags: javascript, orgchart, getorgchart

I am trying to implement an ORG chart using BALKAN GRAPH OrGChartjs . In the BALKAN GRAPH we have something called Slinks , which seems like dotted line connected from one node to another. Is it possible , to drag and drop Slinks from one node to another . I was playing around one [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BALKANGraph/vqgm1a9k/5/)  using OrgChart.redraw() function, but I was unable to do it.  I was able to write this much code, according to my understanding. Appreciate any help.

my JS

```
OrgChart.events.on('redraw', function (sender) {
    var clinkElements = sender.element.querySelectorAll('[c-link-from]');
    for (var i = 0; i < clinkElements.length; i++) {
        var clinkElement = clinkElements[i];
        clinkElement.addEventListener('click', function () {

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: See https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS-Demos/DraggableClinks.html